How do i search for word accross all oneNote notebooks?
I have 40-50 One Note Notebooks. Currently i can only search in a notebook that is open. I want to search in all the notebooks in OneNote, Is that Possible, if so how can i do that ?

In the current version of OneNote, in the search field, click on the down arrow to pop open a dropdown list. In this list, you can select the scope of the search from This Notebook to All Notebooks. You can quickly find the search field by using Ctrl+F.


I tried that and it only search if my oneNote has been opened. I want search to happen even if i did not open the notebook.

Sorry NSS, but search only works on open notebooks. The contents of a notebook are only available when it is open. The notebook information is not stored locally, it is all synced. If you exported every notebook to a PDF or MHT file, you could use a third party tool to search through the files/text to find something. For example, export all the notebooks to MHT and save them in a folder. Then use a tool such as Notepad++ to Find in Files and search the entire directory.
